# How do we know a linear code have even weight?

Tags: coding-theory

In coding theory, How do we know a linear code have even weight?

For example, we have a linear code (12,3,6), how to identify each word of it get even weight?

Answer (score 6):

In every linear binary code,

**either**

*all* the codewords have even weight

**or**

*half* the codewords have even weight and *half* have odd weight

So, if if your question is "How can we tell whether a linear
binary code has codewords
of even weight or not?" then you have nothing to worry about because *all*
linear binary codes have codewords of even weight.

On the other hand, if your question is "How can we tell whether *all*
the codewords in a linear binary code have even weight?" then some
work is needed. One dead giveaway is that if by $[n,k,d]$ is meant
a linear binary code of length $n$ with $2^k$ codewords and minimum
distance $d$, then the code has codewords of odd weight whenever $d$ is
odd.  However, when $d$ is even, one cannot say that there are no codewords
of odd weight.  Consider, for example, the $[5,2,2]$ code with codewords
$$00000, 11000, 00111, 11111$$
So, when $d$ is even, we need more information about the code to figure
out whether the code has only even-weight codewords.

Here is a $[12,3,6]$ code in which all the codewords have even weight.
its generator matrix is given by
$$G = \begin{bmatrix}111&111&000&000\\000&000&111&111\\000&111&111&000\end{bmatrix}$$
Can you figure out a relationship between this code and the $[4,3,2]$ code
consisting of all even-weight binary vectors of length $4$?