# Weights of Binary Linear Code

Tags: coding-theory

I was looking at this problem related to coding theory: [How do we know a linear code have even weight?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821988/how-do-we-know-a-linear-code-have-even-weight)

Can anyone explain how we know either all codewords have even weight or half the codewords have even weight and half have odd weight? This fact seems to just be stated without being proven...

Comment: **Lemma**: Let $q\in \mathbb P$ and let $\mathcal C$ be a linear code over $\mathbb F_q$. All words in $\mathcal C$ start with $0$ or exactly $\frac 1q$ words of $\mathcal C$ start with zero. Prove this lemma and try to use it.

Comment: I'm not sure where to go with proving the lemma... And if $q = 2$ then that would show either all have even weight or half have odd weight assuming the weight is determined by the starting value. But why would starting with $0$ mean the code word is even?

Comment: Extend $\mathcal C$ to $\color{grey}{\overline {\mathcal C}:=}\{1\mathbf{c}\colon \mathbf{c}\in \mathcal C\land \mathbf{w}_H(\mathbf{c})\text{ is odd}\}\cup\{0\mathbf{c}\colon \mathbf{c}\in \mathcal C\land \mathbf{w}_H(\mathbf{c})\text{ is even}\}$ and use the lemma on $\overline{\mathcal C}$.

Comment: That theorem you mention doesn't seem to say much. Suppose not all words have even weight, then there is at least one with odd weight. Therefore not all words of $\overline{\mathcal C}$ start with $0$. Use the lemma and proceed.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding but I think I may have read something that helps. I found a theorem which says for an [n, k] code C, either C is only a set of even-like codewords or the set of even-like codewords is an [n, k-1] subcode of C. So it would make sense that exactly half the words are of odd weight if $n = 2*(k-1)$, correct?

Comment: So you are saying to let $\bar C$ be the set of all codewords in C of odd weight? I don't understand what extending C does.

Comment: No, $\overline{\mathcal C}$ is a code of length $n+1$, where $n$ is the length of $\mathcal C$, $1\mathbf{c}$ is the word obtained by concatenating the one letter word $1$ with $\mathbf{c}$.

Comment: Ah. So we are extending $C$ in such a way that $\bar C$ is the code of length n+1 where all words of even weight start with $0$ and all codes of odd weight start with $1$? Then, by the lemma, if we assume there is at least one code of odd weight then that means at least one word starts with $1$ and therefore in a binary linear code $\frac 12$ words are of odd weight? 
Assuming all of this is right, I'm still not sure how to prove the lemma.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The lemma is another question by itself. But for $q=2$ the proof is greatly simplified. Suppose note all words start with $0$ and consider the sets $\mathcal C_0$ (words of $\mathcal C$ that start with $0$) and $\mathcal C_1$ (analogous). Prove that $\left|\mathcal C_0\right|=\left|\mathcal C_1\right|$ and $\mathcal C_0\dot \cup \mathcal C_1=\mathcal C$. Conclude.

Answer (score 6):

Since the discussion in the comments between @GitGud and the OP seems to converging far too slowly to a solution, and since I wrote the answer wherein the statement in question occurred, here goes with a few hints for a different approach which will,
along the way force you to learn some useful facts about binary vectors.

Suppose $\mathcal C$ denotes a linear binary code. Partition $\mathcal C$ into two
subsets $\mathcal C_0$ and $\mathcal C_1$ consisting respectively
of all the codewords of even
Hamming weight and all the codewords of odd Hamming weight.

- Show that for *every* linear binary code, $\mathcal C_0$ is a non-empty set. Hint: find a codeword of even weight in $\mathcal C$. (Subhint: $0$ is an *even* integer).
- Explain why if $\mathcal C_1$ is an empty set, then we have proved part of the statement in question.

**Digression:**

- Show that the sum of two binary vectors of even Hamming weight is a vector of even Hamming weight.
- Show that the sum of two binary vectors of *odd* Hamming weight is *also*
  a vector of *even* Hamming weight.
- Show that the sum of a binary vector of odd Hamming weight and a binary vector of
  even Hamming weight is a vector of odd Hamming weight.

**End of digression**

Suppose that $\mathcal C_1$ is *non-empty* and let $x$ denote a fixed element of $\mathcal C_1$.

- Show that $x + \mathcal C_0 = \{z \colon z = x + y, y \in \mathcal C_0\}$ is a collection of $|\mathcal C_0|$ distinct vectors, all of which have 
  odd Hamming weight.
  Argue that $x + \mathcal C_0 \subset \mathcal C_1$ and so it must be that
  $|\mathcal C_1| \geq |\mathcal C_0|$.
- Show that 
  $x + \mathcal C_1 = \{u \colon u = x + v, v \in \mathcal C_1\}$ is a collection
  of $|\mathcal C_1|$ distinct vectors all of which have even Hamming weight. Argue
  that $x + \mathcal C_1 \subset \mathcal C_0$ and hence 
  $|\mathcal C_1| \leq |\mathcal C_0|$.

Conclude, if you dare, that either $\mathcal C_1 = \emptyset$ and so
all the codewords in $\mathcal C$ have even Hamming weight, **or**
that $\mathcal C$ contains codewords of even Hamming weight as well as
odd Hamming weight and that 
$$|\mathcal C_1| = |\mathcal C_0| = \frac 12 |\mathcal C|.$$